# How to map users to different data sources

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss, jndi

I have JNDI settings for 2 data sources in Single Application Server (`Jboss 4.2.3`).

How do I identify which user request hit came from which database connection? How do I set the Db connection based on a user request. I need one time DB connection for user.
i.e i want to use dynamic data source in my application. i used pure JDBC connection

Comment: Please clarify, and there are two or three questions (reduce it to a single one). BTW which database?

Comment: I have single Application server (JBoss), in which, i defined 2 Data Source (Both are pointing to oracle DB) , my question is, how we can identify(app server to point which db should use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building a multi-tenancy application.

- So you need another mapping between users and a data source (in DB table for example). Based on that mapping pick the data source.

---

- The users should authenticate against your application, so you can call `request.getRemoteUser()`. Use that to lookup the data source name in the mapping table.

---

- Now you have the name of the data source. Data sources are bound in JNDI, and each data source has a unique name there.

In your application you lookup a data source by its name:

```
final DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/jdbc/x1");
final Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
try {
  // Do something with connection
} finally {
  conn.close();
}
```

so in your case you have two names like `java:/jdbc/x1` and `java:/jdbc/x2`.

You define the JNDI name at the same location where the data source is defined.

Comment: Thanks Beryllium,  i want to know, is there any techniq to pass Data Source Name (Java:/jdbc/x1  or java:/jdbc/x2) in user request ??

Comment: Yes, that's already in the example: Just pass the string argument from a request into the `lookup()` method. Technically possible, but please check that you are not opening any security holes.

Comment: Take my scenario , User A  with x1 Data Source, and USer B with x2 Data Source, whenever user A logs in application at that time i need x1 data Source name in my application, We dont know which user can access application at a time..

Comment: Either pass the user's name as request argument as well (again: check for security holes) or let the user authenticate before; in that  case you can call `request.getRemoteUser()`.

Comment: Actully  i have thousands of users in my Both DB. Some of  A company, some of B company, my application is same for both clients but DB is different. so just want to use DataSource techniq to handle  1 application server with two DB datasource. if u have any another approch please share.

Comment: You are building a multi-tenancy application. So you need another mapping between users and a data source (in DB table). Based on that pick the data source.